# Como diferenciar 2 inputs criados com laço for e fazer operações entre eles

Tags: python

Como faço a soma dos 2 valores digitados pelo usuário?
Meu código:

```
for c in range(0, 2):
    n = int(input('Digite um valor:'))
```

Como diferencio o primeiro valor do segundo para fazer operações como soma e subtração entre eles?

Comment: [Tá abrindo cocos com tanques de guerra?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/64969)

Comment: É que tenho a impressão de que quanto menor for o código, "melhor" ele é.

Comment: Se são sempre 2, não precisa fazer o range.

Comment: Parece-me que uma solução que soltasse uma tupla em uma linha seria algo mais Pythônico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem várias formas de se fazer isso.

Uma delas é criar um array com **todos** os dois valores digitados pelo usuário:

```
n = []
for c in range(0, 2):
    n.append(int(input('Digite um valor:')))

print("A soma é {}".format(sum(n)))
```

Podes criar uma variável que faz a operação a cada laço:

```
sum = 0

for c in range(0, 2):
    n = int(input('Digite um valor:'))
    sum += n

print("A soma é {}".format(sum))
```

Comment: Muito bom o grifo